# How to render <a> tag into nextjs and convert it to next/Link Component

Tags: next.js

i have the string that **rendered** in nextjs component, this string have some links that contain **a tag**.
how to inject nextjs link component instaed a tag that work

Comment: Why do you need to inject it and convert an anchor tag? Can't you just use the Link component instead? Can you show us the code?

Comment: You can use next router. Here is a link of how to use next router https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

After rendering the string as html on the page i wrote this, in one method

```
const router = useRouter();
window.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('nextjs-link')) { // this line check a tag contains class
        e.preventDefault();
        router.push('/');
    }
});
```

Comment: What was your problem with the link itself? You could use an event handler on any tag to route!